# from andriod i am trying to upload image and i am using web services in java

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, multipartform-data

below is the android part

```
new MultipartUploadRequest(this,uploadid,UPLOAD_URL)
                .addFileToUpload(path,"image")
                .addParameter("name",name)
                .setNotificationConfig(new UploadNotificationConfig())
                .setMaxRetries(2)
                .startUpload();
```

below is my java controller in web services

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/uploadm",method=RequestMethod.POST)
public void submitQuestionuploading(@RequestBody String image) throws Exception 
{   
    System.out.println(1+""+image);



        try {


             byte[] bytes = image.getBytes();
             System.out.println(11);
             BufferedOutputStream stream =new BufferedOutputStream(new 
             FileOutputStream(new File(UPLOAD_DIRECTORY +"11.png")));  
             stream.write(bytes);  
             stream.flush();  
             stream.close();
          } 
              catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);

    }
```

output is this one i got in console but file is created but it is corrupted and it s  size 0bytes ,

> ---------AndroidUploadService1518510071115 Content-Disposition: form-data; name="image"; filename="IMG_20180211_000033.jpg"
>   Content-Type: image/jpeg
>
> ÿØÿá3ØExif

i tried to put this in java controller but it is not working

> @RequestMapping(value = "/upload", method = RequestMethod.POST ,
>   headers = "Content-Type=multipart/form-data")     public String
>   fileUpload(@RequestParam("image") CommonsMultipartFile file) {}

but i want to do in spring `MVC` only, help me to take uploaded file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a working file uploader

```
    @ResponseStatus(code = HttpStatus.CREATED)
@RequestMapping(value = "asset", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = {
        MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE}, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE)
@ResponseBody
public String uploadImage(
        @RequestParam("image") MultipartFile file) {
    byte[] bytes = file.getBytes();
    //do something with byte

    return "ok or anything you want to return";
}
```

And also you need to register MultipartResolver as a depandency.

```
@Bean(name = "multipartResolver")
public CommonsMultipartResolver multipartResolver() {
    CommonsMultipartResolver multipartResolver = new CommonsMultipartResolver();
    multipartResolver.setMaxUploadSize(100000);
    return multipartResolver;
}
```

you can deploy this code and then test using postman.

there are various tutorials for this.
you may have a look at

http://www.baeldung.com/spring-file-upload

https://www.boraji.com/spring-4-mvc-file-upload-example-with-commons-fileupload

Comment: i am using maven has a backend  there is  no .xml file other than pom.xml file is it is giving error telling          SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet dispatcher threw exception
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Expected MultipartHttpServletRequest: is a MultipartResolver configured?
 at org.springframework.util.Assert.notNull(Assert.java:115)